# How do I style with XML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

XML Data

```
<moblies>
 <moblie>
    <title>IPhone X</title>
    <image>iphoneX.png</image>
    <price>999</price>
 </moblie>
</moblies>
```

CSS

```
moblies {
  font-size:80%;
  margin:0.5em;
  font-family: Verdana;
  display:block
}

moblie {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin:0.5em;
  padding:0.5em;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
}

title, price {
  display:block;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "xml/data.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: xmlParser
    });
  });

  function xmlParser(xml) {
      $('#load').fadeOut();
      $(xml).find("moblie").each(function()
      {
          $("#container").append('<div class="moblie"><img src="images/' +
            $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="200" height="300" alt ="' +
            $(this).find("title").text() + '" /><br/><div class="title">' +
              $(this).find("title").text() + '<br/>$' +
              $(this).find("price").text() + '</div></div>');
          $(".moblie").fadeIn(1000);
      });
  }
```

I'm trying to style the XML data that I am importing but, can't seem to get the gist of how you actually do that. Above I have provided my XML, CSS and the script I have used to display the data if anyone has any ideas of where I have gone wrong or any research links would be appreciated.

Comment: [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)

Comment: Why would a CSS rule for a `moblie` element style anything if you use Javascript to parse the XML and create HTML `div` elements with `class` attributes? If you want the CSS to be applied to the HTML you create you need `.moblie` or `.title` as the corresponding CSS selectors.

Comment: I tried that and there was no change to the xml data, this is what's in the body, not sure if theres anything wrong with my divs?   <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="container">
        <div align="center" class="loader">
        <img src="images/loading.gif" id="load" width="400" height="400" align="absmiddle"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Have you use the browser's developer tools and checked the error console for any script or network errors? Are you aware that StackOverflow allows you to embed executable HTML/CSS/Javascript snippets in your question to allow us to easily reproduce the problem? There is no need to put your code into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a XML document and a CSS for styling.

So the question is what is your output format? I could only guess it should be HTML - but others like PDF would also be possible (requires [XML-FO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects)).

So what you are trying is not to style XML - it is to transform XML to HTML and applying a stylesheet to this output (HTML).

The best way to do this is to use [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), because this "language" has extra to be designed to transform xml. But doing it by some kind of code like yours is also possible.

Another solution might be to use regexp replacements ...

But last but not least I think you forget to include the stylesheet within your result like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="layout.css" />
```